# Reading log file into DataGridView

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, log-files

I have a log file that i want to present in a DataGridView.

An Example line of data in the file would be :-

```
<![LOG[Creating mandatory request for advert 0002124C, program Shutdown Desktops Overnight, package 0000073C]LOG]!><time="05:00:00.192+000" date="02-11-2013" component="execmgr" context="" type="1" thread="3712" file="execreqmgr.cpp:2858">
```

I want to pull out aspects of the example above, Log Description, Time & Date, component, context, type and Thread.. and add them as columns in the DataGridView's DataSource.

Which is the best way to tackle pulling this data out?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are the values in the Log File comma separated ? if so , split the values into a List and Bind that List<T> to the datagridview or read the values into a dataset or datatable and bind them that way..

Comment: There not comma seperated mate, its exactly as I've posted above. That is one line in the file. It makes it more awkward, not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest DJ Kraze's approach: creating a custom list and binding it to your DataGridView. Just use custom code to parse the line.  You may use a DataTable, too, if you have to, however the List approach is usually cleaner.

Something like (I didn't check the exact syntax or method calls, so use as an example only, you will need a text reader, for example):

```
public class LogEntry {
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
   // other properties you want to extract
}

public class LogReader {
   public List<LogEntry> ReadLog(string fileName){
       var parsedLog = new List<LogEntry>();
       using(var file = File.Open(filename, ....)){
           while(var line = file.ReadLine()){
               var logEntry = ParseLine(line);
               parsedLog.Add(logEntry);
           }
       }
       return parsedLog;
   }

   private LogEntry ParseLine(string line){
       var logEntry = new LogEntry();
       // go through the line and parse it with string functions and populate values.
       // I use a helper class, a shortened version is below - note, you might need to
      //adjust to compile
       var parser = new StringParser(line);
       //now just use GetBetween to find the values you need. just pick your delimiters
       // carefully as the parser will move beyond the end string.  But it will go
       // sequentially so just experiment
      logEntry.Description = parser.GetBetween("LOG[", "]LOG");
      // go through in order
   } 
}

public class StringParser {
    private string text;
    private int position;

    public StringParser(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }  

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.text; }
        private set
        {
            this.text = value;
            Position = 0;
        }
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get { return this.position; }
        private set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                this.position = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.position = value > this.Text.Length ? this.Text.Length : value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool AtEnd
    {
        get { return this.Position >= this.Text.Length; }
    }

    public string GetBetween(string beforeText, string afterText)
    {
        var startPos = MoveAfter(beforeText);
        if (startPos == -1)
        {
            return "";
        }

        var endPos = FindNext(afterText);
        return GetBetween(startPos, endPos);
    }

     public string PeekBetween(int startPos, int endPos)
    {
        if (startPos < 0 || startPos >= this.text.Length)
        {
            return "";
        } 
        if (endPos < 0 || endPos > this.text.Length)
        {
            endPos = this.text.Length;
        } 
        if (startPos >= endPos)
        {
            return "";
        }

        var result = this.text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos);
        return result;
    }

    public string GetBetween(int startPos, int endPos)
    {
        if (endPos < 0 || endPos > this.text.Length)
        {
            endPos = this.text.Length;
        } 
        var result = PeekBetween(startPos, endPos);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            this.Position = endPos;
        }
        return result;
    }


    public int FindNext(string searchText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || this.AtEnd)
        {
            return -1;
        } 
        return this.text.IndexOf(searchText, this.Position, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }   

    public int MoveAfter(string searchText)
    {
        var found = FindNext(searchText);
        if (found > -1)
        {
            found += searchText.Length;
            this.Position = found;
        }
        return found;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Its the parsing part I'm struggling with

Comment: I added a shortened version of the StringParser class I use as an example.  You might need to adjust it, however you generally can get an idea of how to use string functions from it.

Comment: I was adding the parts that were missing.  Basically you are using the string functions IndexOf() to find start and end positions, and then use Substring() to get the string between.